# Trouble with wildcards in snakemake

Tags: python, pandas, wildcard, sample, snakemake

I am having trouble with wildcards not converting to the supposed values. This is the Snakefile:

```
import pandas as pd

configfile: "config.json"
experiments = pd.read_csv(config["experiments"], sep = '\t')
experiments['Name'] = [filename.split('/')[-1].split('_R' if ',' in filename else '.fa')[0] for filename in experiments['Files']]
name2sample = {experiments.iloc[i]['Name'] : experiments.iloc[i]['Sample'] for i in range(len(experiments))}
mg_experiments = experiments[experiments["Data type"] == 'dna']

def preprocess_input(wildcards):
    # get files with matching names
    df = experiments.loc[experiments['Name'] == wildcards.name, 'Files']
    # get first value (in case multiple) and split on commas
    return df.iloc[0].split(',')

def join_reads_input(wildcards):
    df = mg_experiments.loc[mg_experiments['Sample'] == wildcards.sample, 'Files']
    names = [filename.split('/')[-1].split('_R' if ',' in filename else '.fa')[0] for filename in df]
    return ['{}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{}{}.fq'.format(config["output"], name, fr) for name in names
        for files in df for fr in (['_forward_paired', '_reverse_paired'] if ',' in files else [''])]

rule all:
    input:
        expand("{output}/Annotation/uniprotinfo.tsv", output = config["output"], sample = experiments["Sample"]),
        expand("{output}/Annotation/{sample}/protein2cog.tsv", output = config["output"], sample = experiments["Sample"]),
        expand("{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}{fr}.fq", output = config["output"],
            fr = (['_forward_paired', '_reverse_paired'] if experiments["Files"].str.contains(',').tolist() else ''),
               name = experiments['Name'])

rule preprocess:
    input:
        preprocess_input
    output:
        expand("{{output}}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{{name}}{fr}.fq",
            fr = (['_forward_paired', '_reverse_paired'] if experiments["Files"].str.contains(',').tolist() else ''))
    threads:
        config["threads"]
    run:
        shell("python preprocess.py -i {reads} -t {threads} -o {output}/Preprocess -adaptdir MOSCA/Databases/illumina_adapters -rrnadbs MOSCA/Databases/rRNA_databases -d {data_type}",
            output = config["output"], data_type = experiments.loc[experiments['Name'] == wildcards.name]["Data type"].iloc[0], reads = ",".join(input))

rule join_reads:
    input:
        join_reads_input
    output:
        expand("{output}/Assembly/{{sample}}/{{sample}}{fr}.fastq", output = config["output"],
            fr = (['_forward', '_reverse'] if experiments["Files"].str.contains(',').tolist() else ''))
    run:
        for file in input:
            print(file)
            if 'forward' in file:
                shell("touch {output}/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_forward.fastq; cat {file} >> {output}/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_forward.fastq", output = config["output"])
            elif 'reverse' in file:
                shell("touch {output}/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_reverse.fastq; cat {file} >> {output}/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_reverse.fastq", output = config["output"])
            else:
                shell("touch {output}/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}.fastq; cat {file} >> {output}/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}.fastq", output = config["output"])

rule assembly:
    input:
        expand("{output}/Assembly/{{sample}}/{{sample}}{fr}.fastq", output = config["output"],
            fr = (['_forward', '_reverse'] if experiments["Files"].str.contains(',').tolist() else ''))
    output:
        expand("{output}/Assembly/{{sample}}/contigs.fasta", output = config["output"])
    threads:
        config["threads"]
    run:
        reads = ",".join(input)
        shell("python assembly.py -r {reads} -t {threads} -o {output}/Assembly/{{sample}} -a {assembler}",
            output = config["output"], assembler = config["assembler"])
```

which might be very confusing because of noobness on my part. `rule preprocess` runs the preprocess script, `rule join_reads` cats together the reads obtained (the `Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed` part) by sample (defined in the `experiments` file below), so they can be submitted together to assembly. This is the config file:

```
{
  "output": "output",
  "threads": 14,
  "experiments": "experiments.tsv",
  "assembler": "metaspades"
}
```

and this is the experiments.tsv file:

```
Files   Sample  Data type   Condition
path/to/mg_R1.fastq,path/to/mg_R2.fastq Sample  dna
path/to/a/0.01/mt_0.01a_R1.fastq,path/to/a/0.01/mt_0.01a_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c1
path/to/b/0.01/mt_0.01b_R1.fastq,path/to/b/0.01/mt_0.01b_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c1
path/to/c/0.01/mt_0.01c_R1.fastq,path/to/c/0.01/mt_0.01c_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c1
path/to/a/1/mt_1a_R1.fastq,path/to/a/1/mt_1a_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c2
path/to/b/1/mt_1b_R1.fastq,path/to/b/1/mt_1b_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c2
path/to/c/1/mt_1c_R1.fastq,path/to/c/1/mt_1c_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c2
path/to/a/100/mt_100a_R1.fastq,path/to/a/100/mt_100a_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c3
path/to/b/100/mt_100b_R1.fastq,path/to/b/100/mt_100b_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c3
path/to/c/100/mt_100c_R1.fastq,path/to/c/100/mt_100c_R2.fastq   Sample  mrna    c3
```

The problem here is: the cat reports a `MissingOutputException`, because it can't find the file `output/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}_forward.fastq` (and the reverse). It means wildcards.sample didn't convert to "Sample", which I don't understand why. However, the cat rule still manages to produce the files correctly, although it stops the workflow, which has to be executed again. From there it goes well, because the assembly rule already has its input files.

Why is that wildcards.sample not converted to "Sample"?

Comment: What is the reason of having `touch {file}; cat ... >> {file}`? Why don't you remove this `touch`?

Comment: The first cat will not find the file. That solves the problem, and allows to always append!

Comment: Why not to use `cat file1 file2 file3 > {output}`? Moreover, the Snakemake's idiomatic way to separate the files by `'forward'` and `'reverse'` is to use separate rules.

Comment: But the files might be unpaired. I am trying to correspond to both cases :/

Comment: I could simply cat the files with vanilla python, but I wanted something connecting the preprocess rule to the assembly rule

Comment: The idiomatic way to do that in Snakemake is to have separate rules for paired and unpaired cases. Overall your code is hard to read and maintain. Keep it simple.

Comment: What would you suggest here? The problem I see now is that wildcards creates two jobs, one translates correctly to "Sample" while the other translates to literal "wildcards.sample", which fails for no output

Comment: Start from scratch. Design a rule that joins only paired files. Then design a rule for just unpaired. Resolve the ambiguity (if any). Continue refactoring other rules. Keep in mind that most of the times the `run:` section can be replaced with a more explicit `shell:` section.

Comment: So something like this ```rule join_forward:
    input:
        expand("{output}/Preprocess/Trimmomatic/quality_trimmed_{name}_forward_paired.fq", output = config["output"],
            name = lambda wildcards: sample2mgname[wildcards.sample])
    output:
        expand("{output}/Assembly/{{sample}}_forward.fastq", output = config["output"])
    shell:
        "cat {input} > {output}"``` and for reverse and unpaired, where sample2mgname is dictionary that converts sample to the corresponding names

Comment: The only problem here is that wildcards.sample doesn't convert properly. As the syntax is written, shouldn't it convert to "Sample"?

Comment: It should substitute the `{sample}` wildcard with `"Sample"` whenever the file `<output>/Assembly/Sample_forward.fastq` is needed to make the target goal: directly or indirectly.

Comment: Yes, seems that was the problem. I have it working now, the issue was with further rules down that set sample as wildcards.sample. Now the original rule (as posted here) works as intended. Might have been better to separate into distinct rules as you suggested, but for now I just want to have the entire pipeline working properly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot here.  I think for your particular problem, when you use keyword arguments to shell it prevents snakemake from formatting the remaining wildcards.  Change `{output}/Assembly/{wildcards.sample}/{wildcards.sample}_reverse.fastq` to `{output}/Assembly/{sample}/{sample}_reverse.fastq` and pass sample as an argument to shell.

Other suggestions:

- Place input functions above the rules the apply to.
- Use multiple rules instead of complex expands in your inputs/outputs.  You can have two rules with the same output file, one that takes paired inputs and one with unpaired inputs.
- If you have a run directive that just invokes shell, replace that with shell.  You can capture the `reads=','.join(input)` logic into a params directive.  You can directly place config[assembler] into a shell format token, e.g. `shell: python assembly.py ... -a {config[assembler]}`.
- Use `allow_missing` in expand instead of escaping the wildcard formatting with `{{}}`.
- `cat {file} >> {output}` will append the file to output even if the output doesn't exist (don't need the touch).
- Try to keep your lines less than 100 characters so they will display properly on stackoverflow or github.

I think there is a lot of simplification you can do on the logic, but I don't know enough about your tools to recommend more specifics.